# ¿Cómo sumar y restar en una entrada de texto en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

He tratado de hacer una entrada de texto que pueda ser cambiada por un botón, hacer un botón de + que al ser presionado haga que el número en la entrada de texto incremente cada vez que se pulsa el botón.

He probado con este código pero lo que hace es poner el número "1" cada vez que lo pulso...

Código:

```
from tkinter import *
root = tkinter.Tk()
def GetIn(x):
    x=x+1
    entrada.insert(0, x)
    entrada.get()
    return x

entrada = tkinter.Entry(root)
entrada.pack()

x=0

suma_boton = tkinter.Button(root, command=lambda:GetIn(x), text="+")
suma_boton.pack
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que pasar el valor de la entrada como un `int` en vez de usar x

```
entrada.insert(0, 1)
suma_boton = tkinter.Button(root, command = lambda:GetIn( int(entrada.get()) ), text="+")
```

Tu función quedaría así:

```
def GetIn(x):
    x = x + 1
    entrada.delete(0, 'end')  #Necesitas limpiar la entrada
    entrada.insert(0, x)
    entrada.get()
    return x
```